# clojurescript reagent swap! atom negate atom value

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

i tried to invert a value changeval of a reagent atom

```
(def changeval(reagent/atom 0))
...
...
[:input {:type "button" :value "Invert!"
            :on-click #(swap! changeval(not= changeval0 ) ) }]
```

nothing happens, how can I make the changeval = NOT(changeval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter to `swap!` is a function. So I guess it should be:

```
#(swap! changeval (partial not= changeval0))
```

I think `changeval0` is a typo and you want a boolean. In this case check out the Piotrek's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Check the signature of [`swap!`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/swap!) function:

> `(swap! atom f)`
>
> `(swap! atom f x)`
>
> `(swap! atom f x y)`
>
> `(swap! atom f x y & args)`
>
> Atomically swaps the value of atom to be:
>   `(apply f current-value-of-atom args)`. Note that f may be called
>   multiple times, and thus should be free of side effects.  Returns
>   the value that was swapped in.

Thus to negate the value in the atom (it works the same with Clojure's as well as Reagent's atoms) use `not` function (in your case there will be no additional args as you will use only the current value of the atom):

```
(def value (atom true))

(swap! value not)
;; => false

(swap! value not)
;; => true
```

Comment: I understand, third parameter is a function. Now I got "Uncaught TypeError: f.call is not a function"  on line 145 "(-swap! [a f x]        (-reset! a (f state x)))"